# How to find the no of columns affected by a pandas apply method

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which works on a a pandas column.

```
def sales_handler(sales):
     if ssn > 100  #if the value is nan, return missing
        return "ok sales"
```

i am applying this column to one of my columns.

```
df['ssn'].apply(ssn_handler)
```

How do i know the count of columns that was affected. Instead of filtering the column, is there any other way to determine this ?

Comment: It's hard to know how to help more specifically wihtout seeing a [mcve] including sample data, but something like `len(df[df['ssn']>100])`?

Comment: if the issue is with the nan values you can do if pd.isnull(sales) return "missing"

Comment: Are you interested in seeing how many columns are changed after applying your method to the whole dataframe, or do you want to see how many items within one column are changed to "ok sales" and "missing"?  You current example applies the handler function to one column.

Comment: how many rows are changed in a column, the count.

Answer (score 0):

Try using numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'ssn': [150, 150, 300, np.nan, np.nan]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
df['result'] = np.where(df['ssn'] > 100, 'ok sales', 'missing')
```

New column 'result' added to dataframe containing conditional value:

```
df
         ssn    result
    0  150.0  ok sales
    1  150.0  ok sales
    2  300.0  ok sales
    3    NaN   missing
    4    NaN   missing
```

To count occurrences of 'ok sales' and 'missing' in result column of the dataframe:

```
df['result'].value_counts()

ok sales    3
missing     2
Name: result, dtype: int64
```

Re-created your dataframe using 'data'. Used np.nan to simulate NaN values. Assumed column 'ssn' of your dataframe does not have values equal to or less than 100.